# How do I change a local apps locale in LTSP?

Tags: language-support, ltsp

I'm wondering how to change locale (UI gtk) inside local apps to ru_RU for example instead of en_US.

Ror example i install chromium-browser inside client image

```
chroot /opt/ltsp/i386 apt-get -y install chromium-browser
ltsp-update-image --arch=i386
```

booted from thin client
i see LDM in ru_RU lang
login to x session (gnome)
everything is in ru_RU
but trying run

```
ltsp-localapps chromium-browser
```

and see chromium with en_US interface...BUT i need in RUSSIAN

i've added file on both host (`/etc/default/locale)` and thin client image (`/opt/ltsp/i386/etc/default/locale`) with

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

but nothing changed

lts.conf also has `LDM_LANG=ru_RU.utf-8` in it...

Is it possible to change lang of localapps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install also chromium-browser-l10n and then you will have all the languages you need. To install chromium-browser-l10n in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt -y install chromium-browser-l10n
```